# called tcl_findhashentry on deleted table

Tags: tcl

I have a tcl script, it is actually an install script and when I run it, it seems to be working fine until the end where this error pops up:

```
Called Tcl_FindHashEntry on deleted table

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

I did some google research but nothing useful came up.

Comment: Check which extensions are loaded when this occurs. If possible try and reduce the failure to a short demonstration function then post the query to the comp.lang.tcl mailing list, here, or the irc channel on freenode (#tcl). A Tcl script should never cause this sort of error so I suspect some extension you have loaded is the cause.

Comment: It's a bug, but it's not clear _whose_ bug it is yet. Please report the exact version of Tcl being used, and what packages that script uses with it (if any).

Comment: tclsh85.exe, I cannot post the whole code here, but basically the script will first create a pkgIndex.tcl file where it will write the location for the package needed.

Comment: Look, the problem is that it's memory corruption of some kind. That's *always* a bug; it should be impossible for it to happen if the implementations of Tcl and all loaded extension packages are correct. But for anyone to help you, we need to know the **exact** versions of everything being used (well, of tclsh and any packages). To get the detailed version of tclsh, use `info patchlevel`…

Comment: FWIW, it's most likely to happen during application shutdown if heavy finalization is being done (resource deletion order is difficult at the best of times) but that doesn't change whether it's a bug; finalization bugs are just among the hardest to hunt and destroy.

Comment: The immediate cause is attempting to look up an entry in a hash table that has been deleted. That points to something being deleted too early (this is approximately a use-after-free bug). Tracking those down is very hard; the bug is typically not in the immediate locus of the place that detects the fault. We can't even tell from the report whether this is hash table's top level memory is being managed by Tcl (or Tk), which would be actionable by us, or by some application code (which would be someone else's bug). These sorts of faults are awkward to debug! Try a mem-debug build of Tcl.